# how to make bitbake print options of do_configure

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm having trouble cross compiling Qt5 for beaglebone using openembedded with bitbake. I think in step `do_configure` not everything is passed from my *.bbappend and no platform plugins are installed (I need 'linuxfb').

My question will be: how to make bitbake print list of arguments it passes to `./configure`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few ways to get that info, I would suggest looking in the [recipe work directory](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-WORKDIR):

- temp/log.do_configure contains the configure task log which should list exact ./configure-command
- build/ contains the projects own build system artefacts

`bitbake -e <recipe> | grep <VARIABLE>` is very useful if you want to know what variable values end up as (check e.g. PACKAGECONFIG and PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS values if you're modifying packageconfig).